# How do I smooth or 'relax' a 2d mesh resulting from a delaunay triangulation?

Tags: python, c++, opengl, mesh, triangulation

I have used [this](http://dzhelil.info/triangle/) python triangle module to create a mesh of triangles from a set of random 2d point coordinates. What I want now is to, without adding any points or splitting up the triangles, modify the triangle point position so that the triangles are more spaced between each other, so that they are equilateral or closer to equilateral, and more similarly sized. I honestly don't have a clue of how to do this. I would rather also have the actual code than rely on a third party library.

Answer (score 2):

Look for "Laplace" or "Area centroid weighted". More details [here](http://ima.udg.edu/~sellares/ComGeo/SurfMesh.ppt).